# twitter search Api RestSharp not working and giving error unauthorize

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, twitter, twitter-oauth, restsharp

I am trying to develop twitter client. i am using RestSharp for api. its work fine with authentication and gettimeline but its give error when i try to search twitter with # hashtag . its gives error like bad request and unauthorized.

Working code

```
    public string GetTimeLine(string key,string secret,string userToken,string userSecret)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest("/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json", Method.GET);

        Client.Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource(key, secret, userToken, userSecret);

        var response = Client.Execute(request);
        return response.Content;

    }
```

Respond with unauthorized error:

```
    public string GetHashtag(string key, string secret, string userToken, string userSecret)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest("/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23freebandnames", Method.GET);

        Client.Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource(key, secret, userToken, userSecret);

        var response = Client.Execute(request);
        return response.Content;

    }
```

Comment: Please share you client code.

Comment: var t = new Twitter();
            var url = t.GetRequestToken(Key, Secret, "http://2a40682c.ngrok.io/Twitter/Auth");
            
            // t.GetTimeLine(Key, Secret, userToken, userSecret);
            //t.UpdateStatus("first test asp.net tweet #hurrah", Key, Secret, userToken, userSecret);
            ViewBag.ScreenName = "abc";
            ViewBag.tweet = t.GetHashtag(Key, Secret, userToken, userSecret);
            TempData["Tweets"] = new twt { ScreenName = "abc", Tweet = ViewBag.tweet };

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var request = new RestRequest("/1.1/search/tweets.json?q={query}", Method.GET);
request.AddUrlSegment("query", "#freebandnames");
```

Comment: Actually i tried following code and its work fine : var request = new RestRequest("/1.1/search/tweets.json", Method.GET);
            request.AddQueryParameter("q", hashtag);